# Rails - Specify which join column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I have two models `Quote` and `QuoteVersion`. `Quote` has many `QuoteVersions`, and `QuoteVersion` belongs to `Quote`, and `Quote` belongs to `QuoteVersion`, since I want to be able to get the `current_version` by calling `quote.quote_version`, and algo get all the versions by calling `quote.quote_versions`. Is this good design? I find it dirty to find the current_version by using `quote.quote_versions.last`. Thoughts?

I need to create a query to get only the current versions, which I know I can do using the following:

`Quote.joins(:quote_versions).where("quote_versions.id = quotes.quote_version_id")`

, but is there a cleaner way? I need to include several other conditions, like this:
`Quote.joins(:quote_versions).where("quote_versions.id = quotes.quote_version_id").where(quote_versions: { approver_id: nil, approved: nil })`

I think it would be cleaner to be able to do something like:

`Quote.joins(:quote_versions).where(quote_versions: { id: :quote_version_id, approver_id: nil, approved: nil })`, which includes all the conditions in the hash format, I just don't know how to specify the join column on the Quote model to do so, or if it's possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I understand, those "several other conditions" are meant to get the current quote version, so I think you could go with a method:

```
def quote_version
 Quote.joins(:quote_versions).where(quote_versions: {...} ).where(quote_id: self.id)
end
```

Now if you want to clean things a bit up, you could use scopes in your QuoteVersion model:

```
class QuoteVersion < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :not_approved, ->{where(approved_id: nil,approved:nil)}
end
```

And then do something like this in your Quote model

```
def quote_version
  self.quote_versions.not_approved.where(quote_versions: {id: quote_version_id})
end
```

It doesn't look pretty clear what you're trying to accomplish so I hope my answer helps you a little

Comment: The other conditions are to determine whether the quotes are in review, approved, etc. So I first wanted to make sure I can use a clean way to get `Quote.joins(:quote_versions).where("quote_versions.id = quotes.quote_version_id")` part right. The rest of the conditions are pretty straight forward.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the most "clean" solution I see is going with scopes. As for your initial query, I recommend you going with belongs_to